# OTP program argumets and warnings

Tags: intellij-idea, opentripplanner

I've installed OTP using IntelliJ IDEA. I downloaded GTFS and OSM data from Berlin and I create a main configuration to build the graph and the server. Once I run it, it gives me the following warnings:

15:26:18.781 INFO (Graph.java:805) Main graph size: |V|=844791 |E|=1965688 15:26:18.781 INFO (Graph.java:806) Writing graph C:\Users\paula\Desktop\berlindata\Graph.obj ... 15:26:32.793 INFO (Graph.java:844) Graph written. 15:26:32.889 INFO (GraphBuilder.java:171) Graph building took 4,4 minutes. 15:26:32.891 INFO (GraphScanner.java:81) Attempting to automatically register routerIds [route] 15:26:32.891 INFO (GraphScanner.java:82) Graph files will be sought in paths relative to C:\Users\paula\Desktop\berlindata\graphs 15:26:32.893 INFO (GraphService.java:189) Registering new router 'route' 15:26:32.893 WARN (InputStreamGraphSource.java:218) Graph file not found or not openable for routerId 'route': java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\paula\Desktop\berlindata\graphs\route\Graph.obj (El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada) 15:26:32.893 WARN (InputStreamGraphSource.java:144) Unable to load data for router 'route'. 15:26:32.893 WARN (GraphService.java:198) Can't register router ID 'route', no graph. 15:26:32.909 INFO (GrizzlyServer.java:50) Starting OTP Grizzly server on ports 8080 (HTTP) and 8081 (HTTPS) of interface 0.0.0.0 15:26:32.909 INFO (GrizzlyServer.java:52) OTP server base path is C:\Users\paula\Desktop\berlindata 15:26:33.994 WARN (PropertiesHelper.java:330) There is no way how to transform value "true" [java.lang.Boolean] to type [java.lang.String]. 15:26:34.088 INFO (NetworkListener.java:750) Started listener bound to [0.0.0.0:8080] 15:26:34.151 INFO (NetworkListener.java:750) Started listener bound to [0.0.0.0:8081] 15:26:34.151 INFO (HttpServer.java:300) [HttpServer] Started. 15:26:34.151 INFO (GrizzlyServer.java:130) Grizzly server running.

I think my problem is that I'm not writing properly the program arguments. I wrote that:

[program arguments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pn7od.jpg)

Do you know what I should change?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

When you add the "--router route" parameter to the OpenTripPlanner arguments, once the graphs are built OpenTripPlanner will search for a folder called "route" in the `<basePath>\graphs\` folder.

Because you are building the graphs in the basePath folder, you should be able to add the argument "--autoScan" and remove the argument "--router route" and OpenTripPlanner should pick detect the Graph.obj file automatically.

Alternatively, you can move the "Graph.obj" to a folder called `<basePath>\graphs\route` and keep the arguments as they are. Keep in mind though, every time you run that command it will rebuild the OpenTripPlanner Graph.obj file, but load the graph in the `<basePath>\graphs\route` folder. I personally run two separate commands: one to build the OpenTripPlanner graph, and another to start the OpenTripPlanner server with the graph created in the previous step.

The [OpenTripPlanner documentation](http://docs.opentripplanner.org/en/latest/Basic-Usage/) should give you some advice, as well as using the "--help" argument into OpenTripPlanner.

Comment: I've changed the path and folders (i've created a subdirectory w/ the PBF and GTFS files inside) and I've moved the graph.obj as you suggested. However, it returns these warnings: 15:03:37.516 WARN (InputStreamGraphSource.java:218) Graph file not found or not openable for routerId 'berlin': java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\paula\Desktop\graphs\graphs\berlin\Graph.obj (system cannot find the specified path)
15:03:37.516 WARN (InputStreamGraphSource.java:144) Unable to load data for router 'berlin'.
15:03:37.516 WARN (GraphService.java:198) Can't register router ID 'berlin', no graph.

Comment: Sorry @proma - I had a few personal tasks on. Could you please show me the structure of the directories under "C:\Users\paula\Desktop\graphs" and the new OTP commands you are running?

Comment: No problem, I found a solution. --build
C:\Users\paula\Desktop\graphs\viena
--server
--basePath
C:\Users\paula\Desktop
--router
viena Thank you